# Javascript function to change all css items

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, blogger

Is there any javascript function which can change all the given CSS styles to other CSS styles in the following code. See, I want `body`, `.container1`, `.button1`, and all other things in the given link to turn into `body.dark`, `container1.dark` etc.

https://codepen.io/vkdatta27/pen/poyYapw

Comment: You mean, adding classes to those elements?

Answer (score 2):

Why not adapt your css so that you only change one? Keep it clean.

```js
function toggleDark() {
  const body = document.querySelector('body');
  if (body.classList.contains('dark')) {
    body.classList.remove('dark');
  } else {
    body.classList.add('dark');
  }
}

document.querySelector('#darkmode').addEventListener('click', toggleDark);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
}

body.dark {
  background-color: #272727;
}

.container1 {
  width: fit;
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: fit;
  color: green;
}

body.dark .container1 {
  width: fit;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: fit;
  color: red;
}

.container2 {
  width: fit;
  background-color: black;
  height: fit;
  color: white;
}

body.dark .container2 {
  width: fit;
  background-color: white;
  height: fit;
  color: black;
}

.button1 {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black
}

body.dark .button1 {
  background-color: #white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<div class="container1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div><br />
<div class="container2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div><br />
<button id="darkmode" class="button1"> Lights Off!!</button>
```

Comment: Only sensible and scalable solution. Some want to add the class to every element in the page which is insane

Answer (score 0):

Select the button and listen for the `click` event. Whenever you click on a button you'll want to call a function which loops over the elements that you've specified and uses `classList.toggle('dark')` to either add or remove the `.dark` class to these elements.

```
const button = document.querySelector('#darkmode');
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('body, .container1, .button1');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (const element of elements) {
    element.classList.toggle('dark');
  }
});
```

But it might be *way* easier to use the power of CSS. Like so:

```
.container1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.dark .container1 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Now you'll only have to add or remove the `dark` class on an element that is a parent of all your elements, like `body`, to set the dark mode on or off.

```
const button = document.querySelector('#darkmode');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.body.classList.toggle('dark');
});
```

Oh and small sidenote: `fit` is not a valid value for the `width` property. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) for valid values.

Answer (score 0):

firstly give same class to all css items such as `thema`

in js declare one attribute for thema

```js
dark=false;
themas=document.querySelectorAll(".thema");
function Change(){
  dark= dark ? false:true;
    themas.forEach(element=>{
      if(dark){
         element.classList.add("dark");
      }
      else{
        element.classList.remove("dark");
      }
    })
   
  
}
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  }
body.dark{
  background-color: #272727;
  }
.container1 {
 width: fit;
 background-color: lightblue;
 height: fit;
 color: green; 
 }
.container1.dark{
 width: fit;
 background-color: yellow;
 height: fit;
 color: red; 
 }
.container2 {
 width: fit;
 background-color: black;
 height: fit;
 color: white; 
 }
.container2.dark{
 width: fit;
 background-color: white;
 height: fit;
 color: black; 
 } 
.button1 {
  background-color: #c0c0c0;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black
    }
.button1.dark{
  background-color: #white;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 1px solid black
    }
```

```html
<div class="thema container1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div><br />
<div class="thema container2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div><br />
<button id="darkmode" onclick="Change()" class="thema button1"> Lights Off!!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get all div elements using `document.querySelectorAll("div")`, then iterate on all elements using `forEach` and changing its class name.

```html
var el = document.querySelectorAll("div")
function enableDarkMode(){
  el.forEach((a)=>{
    const className = a.className
    a.className=toggleDark(className)
  })
}

function toggleDark(className){
  if(className.endsWith("dark")){
    return className.substring(0, className.length-5)
  }else{
    return className+".dark";
  }
}
```